# Revert commits of local branch from master

Tags: git, commit, revert

I have a feature branch where I have some commits. Then I did run git rebase master and merged that branch back to master.

So it was like

```
git checkout -b somebranch
......some work commits here .....
git checkout master
git fetch
git merge origin/master
git checkout somebranch 
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge  somebranch
```

Now I need to pull out all my commits in somebranch out from master completely, possible will need to merge it back to master later.

Update: changes were pushed to master some time ago and there is many commits after merge, so reset to head will not work

Comment: I'm neither completely understanding the question, nor I get how that relates to *revert*.

Comment: please feel about revert as delete, not as git revert command. I just need to remove changes I did in branch out of master. But I'm pretty sure it related to git revert also

Comment: why not reset master to where it was before rebase/merge of the feature branch?

Comment: because other people also push to master and there is a lot of changes on top of what going to be removed

Comment: I see, have you tried reverting your range of commits on local copy of master and testing it? i.e. `git revert -n master~5..master~2`

Comment: I asking how to do that, so no. Please post as answer and I'll try

Comment: BTW the fact that you pushed ("some time ago") is relevant to the solution - you could usefully add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout -b somebranch # from "A"
......some work commits here x, y, z .....
git checkout master
git pull # call new HEAD "B"
```

So we have something like

```
A -> a1 -> a2 -> B <= master
 \
  x -> y -> z      <= somebranch
```

and then:

```
git checkout somebranch 
git rebase master

A -> ... -> B <= master
             \
              x' -> y' -> z' <= somebranch

git checkout master
git merge  somebranch # call new HEAD "C"


A -> ... -> B -------------> C <= master
             \              /
              x' -> y' -> z' <= somebranch
```

So, at this point, you can easily *undo* your unwanted merge, by just rewinding master to `B`. However, once you *push* `C` (and other people have seen it, and/or done work on top of it), this becomes hard.

---

The simple solution is to just revert all commits on `somebranch`:

```
git revert x'..z'
```

and push.

Now, before you can merge `somebranch` again, you'll have to rebase it (like you did originally). This works, but you do end up with some noise in the history of master.

---

If a limited number of people have seen and/or committed children, and you can coordinate with them, it's possible to avoid this, but it's a lot of work.
You have to make sure everything they're working on is committed and pushed if possible, and then you can rebase this:

```
A -> ... -> B -------------> C -> c1 -> c2 -> D <= master
             \              /
              x' -> y' -> z' <= somebranch
```

to this:

```
              c1' -> c2' -> D' <= master
             /
A -> ... -> B -------------> C -> c1 -> c2 -> D
             \              /
              x' -> y' -> z' <= somebranch
```

Now the middle branch will be orphaned, the new head `D'` doesn't have your changes, and `somebranch` is still intact so you can merge later.

To do this, use:

```
git rebase --onto B C c1
git push --force
```

Everyone else will now have to update to the new head `D'`, for example by doing:

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that if anyone *does* have local commits that still depend on `C` (and aren't already visible in the `c1..D` chain when you rebase), they'll need to rebase or cherry-pick them across to the new history. This is potentially a lot of (error-prone) work, so better to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1):

On local copy of `master` you can try the following which will create a new commit with the reverted changes (the reverse of what you have already done on master).

`git revert OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT`

where `OLDER_COMMIT` is the first commit of your feature branch commit and `NEWER_COMMIT` is the last commit of your feature branch.

Or alternatively, you can try

`git revert -n OLDER_COMMIT..NEWER_COMMIT`

which will revert the changes done by commits but does not create any new commit with the reverted changes. The revert only modifies the working tree and the index.

Note: with use of `1.7.4+`

Answer (score 0):

If the merge commit is still the latest, and if you have not yet pushed that commit back upstream, `git reset --hard HEAD^` should put you back on the commit before the merge - i.e. return your `master` branch to where it was after `git merge origin/master`.

Comment: change I talking about is old and was pushed some time ago, and there is many commits above it in master

Comment: In that case, it might get messy. Off the top of my head, I would suggest 1) create a new branch at the commit before the problematic merge, 2) cherry pick everything after the merge onto the new branch, 3) declare that your new master. Of course, that has upstream ramifications since it's already been pushed, but that's probably the most straightforward way to eliminate that one merge commit...